# Distinguishing development mode and release mode environment settings on Android

Tags: android, development-environment, release-management

I'm building an Android application and would like to maintain a few environment variables that I can tweak depending on whether I'm in development mode or release mode. For example, I need to invoke a web service and the URL will be slightly different in either mode.  I'd like to externalize this and other settings so I can change them easily based on my target deployment.

Are there any best practices or anything in the SDK to assist with this need?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029819/android-automatically-choose-debug-release-maps-api-key/3828864), in SDK Tools version 17 (we're on 19 as of this writing) adds a `BuildConfig.DEBUG` constant that is true when building a dev build.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer now because it will likely be more applicable to future travelers

Comment: Works for me in **API 15**, 4.0.3.

Comment: API does not matter, just the build tools version.

Answer (score 44):

The following solution assumes that in manifest file you always set `android:debuggable=true` while developing and `android:debuggable=false` for application release.

Now you can check this attribute's value from your code by checking the `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE` flag in the `ApplicationInfo` obtained from `PackageManager`.

The following code snippet could help:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = ... // get package info for your context
int flags = packageInfo.applicationInfo.flags; 
if ((flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
    // development mode
} else {
    // release mode
}
```

Comment: As of the more recent SDK versions this would seem the best approach, as both Eclipse and Ant set this automatically depending on build type.

Answer (score 9):

@viktor-bresan Thanks for a useful solution. It'd be more helpful if you just included a general way to retrieve the current application's context to make it a fully working example. Something along the lines of the below:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
```

Answer (score 9):

## Android build.gradle has Handles Debug and Release Environment well.

Append the following code snippet in `build.gradle` file

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "IS_DEBUG_MODE", 'true'
    }

    release {
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "IS_DEBUG_MODE", 'false'
    }
}
```

Now you can access the variable like below

```
    if (BuildConfig.IS_DEBUG_MODE) { {
        //Debug mode.
    } else {
        //Release mode
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I would check out [isDebuggerConnected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#isDebuggerConnected%28%29)

Comment: Thanks, that may come in handy one day, but I can technically be running the emulator in development mode w/o a debugger attached.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like the code below ...

```
public void onCreate Bundle b ) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   if ( signedWithDebugKey(this,this.getClass()) ) {
     blah blah blah
   }

  blah 
    blah 
      blah

}

static final String DEBUGKEY = 
      "get the debug key from logcat after calling the function below once from the emulator";    


public static boolean signedWithDebugKey(Context context, Class<?> cls) 
{
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context, cls);
        PackageInfo pinfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(comp.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        Signature sigs[] = pinfo.signatures;
        for ( int i = 0; i < sigs.length;i++)
        Log.d(TAG,sigs[i].toCharsString());
        if (DEBUGKEY.equals(sigs[0].toCharsString())) {
            result = true;
            Log.d(TAG,"package has been signed with the debug key");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"package signed with a key other than the debug key");
        }

    } catch (android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: The DEBUGKEY in this case is actually the entire certificate. I recommend using the method in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122401/android-compare-signature-of-current-package-with-debug-keystore instead. This way, you're not limited to the debug key from a single machine.

Answer (score 1):

I came across another approach today by accident that seems really straight forward..  Look at Build.TAGS, when the app is created for development this evaluates to the String "test-keys".

Doesn't get much easier than a string compare.

Also Build.MODEL and Build.PRODUCT evaluate to the String "google_sdk" on the emulator!

Comment: Is this reliable? It seems like test-keys could be set for rooted devices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device

That makes me think there may be other instances where this approach could fail.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method I use:

http://whereblogger.klaki.net/2009/10/choosing-android-maps-api-key-at-run.html

I use it to toggle debug logging and the maps API key.

Comment: This makes you hard-code your keys in Java, which is bad and not a generic method.