# Google map displayed in android version 2.2,not displayed in android version 2.1

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am developed application with google map in android 2.2 version using eclipse and ubuntu.in that case I can get the google map as well as the location perfectly.

but now i have to run that same apps in Xp machine with android 2.1 version It run properly but the google map not displayed ,only white screen with boxes  displayed.

Reason for this running in xp is i have to run that application in android device.I have android 2.1 device in samsung ,This only support XP not supporting ubuntu.

So any one help me what are the changes i have to include in my application that will run in android 2.1 in Xp machine.

Answer (score 1):

You are running unsigned builds of your apk on the emulator. The Maps API key you are using must have been derived from the debug certificate of the 2.2 SDK on your Ubuntu machine. You will need to generate a different key for the 2.1 SDK on your XP machine. See [this SDK article](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint) for more information on how to do this.

Comment: @Lakshmanan - you can also adapt method described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029819/android-automatically-choose-debug-release-maps-api-key or better just use the same debug certificate on both machines

Comment: Thanks for ur answers Reuben,And suppose if am using android 2.2 in both xp and ubuntu machine mean  in that case too will i need  to generate debug certificate?

Comment: The debug certificate is part of the SDK, I understand from a quick Google that it is generated for you at install time (and therefore the certificate for every SDK install is different). Note that this is solely for running unsigned .apks... if you're planning to sign your app so it can ship in the Market etc, you will use a Maps API key generated from your own keystore. The technique tomash links to is very useful for avoiding having to switching keys every time you want to run a signed version of the app.