# Android run a project on device with automatic signing? how?

Tags: android

I have an app, that uses mapview. i can only see the map, when i signing my apk file, but it is a long time to signing every time. Is there a way to run my mapview .apk file with automatic signing?

How?

Thanks, Leslie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a mapkey with your debug.keystore and use it in you mapview.

Answer (score 0):

I find detecting if the app has been signed by the debug.keystore and switching Map API keys like that is a nice automatic and reliable way to ensure that the correct map api key is being used

Find out more information at 
[Android: automatically choose debug/release Maps api key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029819/android-automatically-choose-debug-release-maps-api-key/3828864#3828864)

Answer (score 0):

First create a [maps key here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/maps-api-signup.html). 
Insert your map view like this:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mv_circuit_search_google_maps"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true" 
        android:apiKey="YOURMAPSKEY" />
```

If you want to send the app to another device go to your projekt on the filesystem and into the folder bin. 
There is your .apk with the debug key. You can use this app one year.