# Is there a way to determine whether an Android application is signed for production or debug at runtime?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, signing

Is there a way to determine whether an Android application is signed for production or debug  at runtime?

Comment: It has been a while, and I've grew up since then... :) here is a link to a full solution: http://android-know-how-to.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/android-apk-signature-check.html#chitika_close_button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but no 100% reliable. The default (auto-generated) certificate has the DN 'CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US' as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode). If you check the DN and it matches the default, it is most probably the debug certificate. Nothing prevents people from generating their own debug certificate or using the same one for production and debugging though.

You can get the signing certificate using `PackageManager`. Something like:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Signature sig = pm.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 
   PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures[0];
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(sig.toByteArray()));
String dn = cert.getIssuerDN().getName();
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but how can I get this info in runtime?

Comment: This is very informative, but the other solution seems simpler and works.

Comment: Sure, whatever works for you. Just note that it doesn't technically check the certificate, just if it is a debug build or not.

Comment: Yes, that is why I posted my comment on the other answer.

Comment: This is a better way! I tried the other one. just need to add: boolean debuggable=dn.contains(${debugCertificateLabel})

Answer (score 7):

```
private static Boolean isDebugBuild = null;
    protected boolean isDebugBuild() {
        if(isDebugBuild == null) {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            try {
                PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
                isSignedWithDebugKey = (pi.applicationInfo.flags &
                    ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0;
            }
            catch(NameNotFoundException nnfe) {
                nnfe.printStackTrace();
                isDebugBuild = false;
            }
        }

        return isDebugBuild;
    }
```

Since [ADT 8](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), if you don't specifically add debuggable="true" to your manifest, debug builds will have it set to true, and exported / signed builds will have it set to false.

It sounds like this is might be a more reliable method (as long as you don't manually set debuggable..) to determine if it is a debug vs release build, but not specifically if the certificate was a debug cert - which was your question, so my answer might not be relevant for you.

Comment: This is also my implementation, until I would see a proper answer, are you 100% sure that if I don't specify a debuggable attribute in the manifest, the debug certificate sets it to true?

Comment: From the docs: "Support for true debug build. You no longer need to change the value of the debuggable attribute in the Android Manifest.
Incremental builds automatically insert debuggable="true", but if you perform "export signed/unsigned application package", ADT does not insert it. If you manually set debuggable="true" in the manifest file, then release builds will actually create a debug build (it does not remove it if you placed it there)."

I've used this technique for switching map api keys.

Comment: By the way, how did you make sure you really use the correct key? I mean in debug you can print to the log, but on production you cannot print to the log nor to debug and see the value set as the key?

Comment: I've tested this with a toast, and the result is as expected... thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

We use a much simpler way:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    // we're in debug mode
} else {
    // we're in production mode
}
```

Comment: This is a simpler solution for a simple requirement... what happens when you want to have more then two certificates, and want the same application to behaves in 3 or 4 different ways? yes you could add a metadata tag to your manifest during the CI, but then you need a CI. the solution suggested in the blog post is remarkably useful... I had doubts about it while implementing it, but today it distinct a Debug,Staging, and production environments, and exposes specific features respectively to the certificate.

Comment: Yes I fully agree with you, but sometimes there are much simpler needs and my sugestion aims to that simple needs. Luckily the world is not enteirely black or white although the globalists want it to go that way.. but that's another story :)

Comment: True. The actual reason for this is that in the earlier ADT releases, the DEBUG field didn't indicate really whether the application is in debug mode or not, in one version of the adt it did, and then it didn't and it happened multiple time, so a more secure method was needed, and that is how this idea was born.

Answer (score 0):

The post [android-automatically-choose-debug-release-maps-api-key](http://android-automatically-choose-debug-release-maps-api-key)  Has another packagemanger based solution. Basicaly you compare to the hashCode of the actual signatuse.  Working well for me for sorting out the maps key automaticaly