# How do I maintain separate production settings for my Android apps?

Tags: android, configuration

I'm developing one of my first Android apps. I come from an ASP.NET world where it's trivial to have separate Web.config files for dev, test, and production. Does anyone have a good, automated way of doing this for Android via Eclipse?

Comment: I should clarify, what I'm looking for is a good automated way of maintaining separate res/values/*.xml files for dev, test, and production.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1743683/214184
It worked out great for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have a command line ant based build system that takes "dev", "test", "production" as parameters and copies in the appropriate xml files for the build. This assumes that you already have a set of xml/config files for them.

Answer (score 1):

*I know question is late, but I will answer.*

For have separate build for 'dev', 'test', 'production' you may use **Gradle**.

In **build.gradle** file you may define separate `buildTypes` like this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
      runProguard false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      debuggable false
      versionNameSuffix "r"
    }

    debug {
      versionNameSuffix "d"
      debuggable true
    }

    test {
      applicationIdSuffix ".test"
      versionNameSuffix "t"
      debuggable false
    }
```

The above snippet achieves the following:

- config **release**, **debug**, and **test** builds
- set `versionNameSuffix` to refer to the version string which is build
- set `applicationIdSuffix` for may install **test** and **release** build on one device
- and most usefull **Gradle** Build Types can contribute to the build with resources: *src/**[buildtypename]**/res*. So you can have separate resource for separate builds.

For more info go to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide