# Android compare signature of current package with debug.keystore

Tags: android, apk, signature

As all we do I have application which is signed by debug.keystore (by default) when it is in development mode (build). When it goes production we sign it with our private key.
Is there any way to determine at runtime that current package is signed with debug.keystore (is in development mode) or is signed with our private key (is in production mode).

I have tried something like

```
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    try {
        Signature[] signs = packageManager.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
        for (Signature signature : signs) {
            Log.d(TAG, "sign = " + signature.toCharsString());
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I don't know what to do next? Is this right way of doing this? How to obtain comparable debug.keystore signature?

I know that exists MD5 Fingerprint `keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore` but in Signature class there is not "md5 fingerprint"-like method.
I want to do this because of MapView Key, Logging, LicenseChecker and stuff like this.

Comment: Nowadays I use 1 static boolean value which I have to change everytime I do production release. It has happened that I forgot. :(

Answer (score 18):

The signature in `PackageInfo` does not seem to be well named since tha field does not contain the package signature but the signer X509 certificate chain. Note that (most of the time) this chain seems to be limited to one single self-signed certificate.

According to the Android developer page [*Signing Your Applications*](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) the debug signature certificate is generated with this DN: `CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US`

Therefore it is easy to test if the application has been signed in debug mode:

```
private static final X500Principal DEBUG_DN = new X500Principal("CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US");
/* ... */
Signature raw = packageManager.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures[0];
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(raw.toByteArray()));
boolean debug = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().equals(DEBUG_DN);
```

Comment: `DEBUG_DN` is of type `X500Principal`. which is a container for X.500 names

Comment: is it efficient enough to be ran on the onCreate of the application class?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Jcs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203440/115866), we use this to find out at runtime who built the running package:

```
private enum BuildSigner {
    unknown,
    Joe,
    Carl,
    Linda
}

private BuildSigner whoBuiltThis() {
    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        Signature[] signs = info.signatures;
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(signs[0].toByteArray()));
        PublicKey key = cert.getPublicKey();
        int modulusHash = ((RSAPublicKey)key).getModulus().hashCode();
        switch (modulusHash) {
            case 123456789:
                return BuildSigner.Joe;
            case 424242424:
                return BuildSigner.Carl;
            case -975318462:
                return BuildSigner.Linda;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return BuildSigner.unknown;
}
```

For any involved certificate, you then just have to find the hash once and add it to the list.

The simplest way to "find the hash once" may be to just add a popup toast before the switch statement that displays `modulusHash`, compile your app, run it, write down the hash, remove the toast code and add the hash to the list.

Alternatively, when I implemented this, I created a little boilerplate app with a single activity and a single `TextView` with the ID `tv` in the main layout, put this into the activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    int hash = 0;
    try{
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                "com.stackexchange.marvin", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        Signature[] signs = info.signatures;
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(signs[0].toByteArray()));
        PublicKey key = cert.getPublicKey();
        hash = ((RSAPublicKey) key).getModulus().hashCode();
    }catch(Exception e){}

    TextView tv = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv));
    tv.setText("The Stack Exchange app's signature hash is " + hash + ".");
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24);
}
```

(change `com.stackexchange.marvin` to your app's name), compiled this mini-app, and sent the APK to all involved developers, asking them to run it on their dev device and let me know the displayed hash.

Comment: Thanks for info...but how to find hash of the certificate ? Is it the hash of 'key alias' string in the certificate ?