# Determining if an Android device is rooted programmatically?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine if running on a rooted device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device)

How do you determine (programmatically) if an Android device is: rooted Running a cracked copy of your software or rom.

I have some sensitive information in my database, and I would like to encrypt it when the phone is rooted aka the user has access to the database. How do I detect that?

Comment: There is Safety Net Attestation API of Google play services by which we can assess the device and determine if it is rooted/tampered.

Please go through my answer to deal with rooted devices:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58304556/3908895

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Rooting detection is a cat and mouse game and it is hard to make rooting detection that will work on all devices for all cases.

See **Android Root Beer** https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer for advanced root detection which also uses JNI and native CPP code compiled into .so native library.

If you need some *simple and basic* rooting detection check the code below:

```
  /**
   * Checks if the device is rooted.
   *
   * @return <code>true</code> if the device is rooted, <code>false</code> otherwise.
   */
  public static boolean isRooted() {

    // get from build info
    String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
    if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
      return true;
    }

    // check if /system/app/Superuser.apk is present
    try {
      File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
      if (file.exists()) {
        return true;
      }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      // ignore
    }

    // try executing commands
    return canExecuteCommand("/system/xbin/which su")
        || canExecuteCommand("/system/bin/which su") || canExecuteCommand("which su");
  }

  // executes a command on the system
  private static boolean canExecuteCommand(String command) {
    boolean executedSuccesfully;
    try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
      executedSuccesfully = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      executedSuccesfully = false;
    }

    return executedSuccesfully;
  }
```

Probably not always correct. Tested on ~10 devices in 2014.

Comment: You mean rooted with a specific tool that adds Superuser.apk ? There isn't a guaranteed programmatic way to determine if a device is rooted as most checks could be circumvented.

Comment: I've been using this check in my product, but recently the Nexus 7.1 is reporting false for all of these (no `which` command installed) and SuperSu is not installing in the /system/app folder.

Comment: May be you should also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device

Comment: when i implement this code i have this error: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/system/xbin/which, su] Working Directory: null Environment: null
catching in exec At <ProcessManager.java> (Line: 320)

Comment: not working in my phone LeEco 2

Comment: Not working on Galaxy S7 edge

Comment: doesnt work for Redmi 3s prime, executes which su command in that case

Answer (score 5):

If the information is sensitive you should probably just encrypt it for all users.  Otherwise a user could install your app unrooted, then root and read your database once the data's been written.

Comment: Problem is that if your content is media content (mp3, mp4), even encrypted originally, and you want to playback in the media player, you need to use a temporary decrypted file at some point, which could be accessed on a rooted device.

Answer (score 2):

The [official licensing guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) says:

> A limitation of the legacy
>   copy-protection mechanism on Android
>   Market is that applications using it
>   can be installed only on compatible
>   devices that provide a secure internal
>   storage environment. For example, a
>   copy-protected application cannot be
>   downloaded from Market to a device
>   that provides root access, and the
>   application cannot be installed to a
>   device's SD card.

It seems that you would benefit from using that legacy cop-protection to prevent your application from being installed on rooted devices.

You might release a separate version that can be installed on rooted devices with an encrypted database.

Comment: But how can they detect whether the device is rooted or not? As hackbod (Android developer) mentioned, it's not possible to detect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576989/how-can-you-detect-if-the-device-is-rooted-in-the-app