# How to check if android phone is rooted?

Tags: android, root

I want to programatically find in my application if the android phone is rooted.  I found many links like: [Determine if running on a rooted device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device)
[Effective way to programatically check if I'm rooted on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954336/effective-way-to-programatically-check-if-im-rooted-on-android) discussing on the same topic.  However, as mentioned in those links there is no one and definite way to find out.  These posts are pretty old and I was wondering if there is anything better to achieve it now in recent releases?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You won't get answer on this forum with such question. You should try out some of your/gathered ideas and ask about a problem you met while implementing it. On the other hand some idea would be to have a couple of methods that try each scenario (call `su`, request superuser permission, try to write on a privileged folder...) and if any is successful then you're on a rooted device.

Comment: My main intention by posting the question was to find out if there is any thing recent added in android framework to check for root.  Apparently not! I am getting the same answers as in older posts.  Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 20):

I've wrapped this code (working ok without any other external jar/lib) from [RootTools](https://code.google.com/p/roottools/)

```
private static boolean isRooted() {
    return findBinary("su");
}



public static boolean findBinary(String binaryName) {
    boolean found = false;
    if (!found) {
        String[] places = {"/sbin/", "/system/bin/", "/system/xbin/", "/data/local/xbin/",
                "/data/local/bin/", "/system/sd/xbin/", "/system/bin/failsafe/", "/data/local/"};
        for (String where : places) {
            if ( new File( where + binaryName ).exists() ) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: This provides a good long list of possible places where su can exists.   Thanks!

Comment: Well, this is basically the same method like roottools is using: https://code.google.com/p/roottools/source/browse/trunk/Stable/RootTools-sdk3-generic/src/com/stericson/RootTools/internal/RootToolsInternalMethods.java#597
Even the array content is in the same order ;)

Comment: @MatF as you can see I already said in my answer. I wrapped that code FROM RootTools...

Answer (score 5):

You can use the roottools library. They offer a method to check for root access.
https://code.google.com/p/roottools/

Comment: Thanks.  I am aware of roottools library.  It solves the purpose.  Though was looking for some third-party independent solution.

Comment: @Keya did you got any third party indepent solutions or some API to detect rooting in Android phones

Comment: Hey Learner,  sorry I didn't find any solution.  I was looking it for a POC but then we shifted our technique.  Hence didn't pursue it further.  Do update if you find anything.  Thanks!