# How to prevent Rooted Android Phones from Installing my app?

Tags: android, mobile, anti-cheat

The purpose in this context is to prevent false high scores(my app is a game) from being reported in LeaderBoard. This occurred for Flappy Birds - see this link -  http://www.androidpit.com/forum/589832/flappy-bird-high-score-cheat-set-your-own-high-score

Since a root user can do anything he wants with his mobile, I suppose none of the other work around will work and the only solution is to prevent rooted users from installing the app. Am I right? Is there a way to do it?

PS: My game doesn't need internet connection always, hence reporting the scores as and when it happens to another server is not viable. The high scores are reported to leaderboard only when internet connection is available.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had a similar requirement. I couldn't achieve that *app should not be installed on rooted device*, but I used a work around for that:

- Check if your device is rooted in your activity's `onResume`.
- If its rooted, just show him alert "This device is rooted. You can't use this app.", and exit from application.

**Example:**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    if(new DeviceUtils().isDeviceRooted(getApplicationContext())){
        showAlertDialogAndExitApp("This device is rooted. You can't use this app.");
    }
}


public void showAlertDialogAndExitApp(String message) {

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

`DeviceUtis.java` was a Utility class which returned if a device is rooted or not.

```
public class DeviceUtils {

    public Boolean isDeviceRooted(Context context){
        boolean isRooted = isrooted1() || isrooted2();
        return isRooted;
    }

    private boolean isrooted1() {

        File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
        if (file.exists()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // try executing commands
    private boolean isrooted2() {
        return canExecuteCommand("/system/xbin/which su")
                || canExecuteCommand("/system/bin/which su")
                || canExecuteCommand("which su");
    }
}
```

We had used 5 methods for testing, and I have just shown 2 here. You can use any of methods you find good.

Hope this helps.

**P.S:** I have put this call in all activity's `onResume` as user (with intention of hacking) can install application, navigate to some other activity, and then root device.

Comment: can u say, any possibilities is there for , before install the app like while installing the app in android device, can we check If the device is rooted or not ?

Comment: But why in onResume(), why not in onCreate() method, i think it will be good if its on onCreate() in all activities.

Comment: The user can bypass the alert by pressing the back button.

Answer (score 6):

```
private static boolean canExecuteCommand(String command) {
        boolean executedSuccesfully;
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            executedSuccesfully = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            executedSuccesfully = false;
        }

        return executedSuccesfully;
    }
```

Comment: What is a command here? If you can explain how it works that will be appriciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to block users with rooted phones as it normal user behaviour. So, what kind of danger or damage do you fear if you have no online connection for highscores, in-app purchases or the like in your game?

The player wants to cheat her way to the last level or to the top of the local(!) leaderboard? Where is the damage?

By preventing your game from running on rooted devices gains you nothing but repell legitimate users of your app.

Edit:

*Use the cloud save service to save the player's highscores. if offline it will be encrypted and stored on the device. The next time online you read the highscore and send it to the play service. The play service provides an anti piracy feature you also might want.*

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I've reworded the PS. MY game NEEDS  internet connection(to report scores to leaderboard) but NOT ALWAYS(hence to check whether the score is "valid or not" on gameovers always, fails).

Comment: @DroidHeaven Ah okay, I misunderstood then. Are you using Google Play Services oder do you roll your own leader board system?

Comment: I use Google Play Services

Comment: @DroidHeaven Then it is easier. Use the cloud save service to save the player's highscores. if offline it will be encrypted and stored on the device. The next time online you read the highscore and send it to the play service. The play service provides an anti piracy feature you also might want.

Comment: aah now I am confused as to which answer should I accept. Yours and  the one below are both valid:)

Answer (score 3):

With Kotlin Extention you can check easily that, is device is rooted or not. below is the code which may help you out

`DeviceUtils.kt`

```
object DeviceUtils {
    fun isDeviceRooted(context: Context?): Boolean {
        return isRooted1 || isRooted2
    }

    private val isRooted1: Boolean
        get() {
            val file = File("/system/app/Superuser.apk")
            return file.exists()
        }

    // try executing commands
    private val isRooted2: Boolean
        get() = (canExecuteCommand("/system/xbin/which su")
                || canExecuteCommand("/system/bin/which su")
                || canExecuteCommand("which su"))

    private fun canExecuteCommand(command: String): Boolean {
        return try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
            true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

`Extention.kt`

```
fun Activity.checkDeviceRoot(): Boolean {
    return if (DeviceUtils.isDeviceRooted(this)) {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Your device is rooted. you can not use this app into rooted device.")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_ok) { _, _ ->
                    exitProcess(0)
                }.show()
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

How to use this extention:

```
class MyActivity : Activity{
    ...
    override 
    fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        if(checkDeviceRoot())
            return
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

Hope This answer will help you out.

Comment: It is returning isRooted1= false and isRooted2= true even if the device is not rooted.

Answer (score 0):

We have an option in playstore console of **SafetyNet exclusion**, which we can use to prevent app to appear on playstore for downloading on rooted devices.

 
There is **Safety Net Attestation API** of **Google play services** by which we can assess the device and determine if it is rooted/tampered.

To whom who want to deal with rooted device, please go through my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58304556/3908895

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Firebase crashlytics in your project.**
you can use this method where ever is suitable for you. it is recommended to use it in onResume of your activity and then show a dialog to exit the application. I have tested this on the [Nox](https://www.bignox.com/) emulator and worked fine.
However, through my research for this purpose, I did not find a way that covers all the cases the user can always do some workaround to use the application.

```
CommonUtils.isRooted()
```