# Set up root emulator android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, rooted-device

I need to block access to my android application on rooted devices. So when the app is launching I check if there is a file named "Superuser.apk" on the device (see the post of this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540545/how-to-prevent-rooted-android-phones-from-installing-my-app)). If the file exist the application quit.

But here is my real problem, I want to test this feature and I don't want to root my own device. So I was wondering if there is a way to root an emulator on Android Studio to try it ?

I checked a lot of topic on internet, but every post I saw was about how to root a real device.

Is someone there know if it's possible ? And if yes, how?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: faster way is to buy an old and cheap used device from any market...If it is possible, perhaps it is...but I say, it is very tricky and time consuming. I wouldn't do that