# Android root detection not working with mentioned code

Tags: java, android

I'm using following code for root detection in Android device. But still my security expert saying it can be installed and run in rooted device. Could someone detect what the issue with my code

```
public static boolean isDeviceRooted() {
  // get from build info
  String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
  if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
    return true;
  }
  return checkFiles() || checkLocations();
  }
   private static boolean checkFiles(){
String[] files = {
    "/system/app/Superuser.apk",
    "/system/etc/init.d/99SuperSUDaemon",
    "/dev/com.koushikdutta.superuser.daemon/",
    "/system/xbin/daemonsu"
};
for (String fileData : files) {
    try {
        File file = new File(fileData);
        if (file.exists()) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
          // ignore
    }
}
return false;
  }
   private static boolean checkLocations(){
String su = "su";
String[] locations = {
    "/system/bin/",
    "/system/xbin/",
    "/sbin/",
    "/system/sd/xbin/",
    "/system/bin/failsafe/",
    "/data/local/xbin/",
    "/data/local/bin/",
    "/data/local/",
    "/system/sbin/",
    "/usr/bin/",
    "/vendor/bin/"
};
for (String location : locations) {
    if (new File(location + su).exists()) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
  }
```

Comment: Advice? What is the problem? And what is the question?

Comment: https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer

Comment: Superuser is pretty outdated, modern devices are all rooted via Magisk. But with root permissions you can hide everything from an app. Perform at least Google SafetyNet check and validate the result on server side.

Comment: "security expert saying it can be installed". Is installing or running the requirement? because preventing installing is impossible I think. As for running, maybe this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540545/how-to-prevent-rooted-android-phones-from-installing-my-app

Comment: @Robert you comment was useful SafetyNet has several limitations, hence checking for alternative solutions.

Comment: Google SafetyNet check is the only solution that can not bypassed (on some devices) as it is executed in TEE. Therefore there is no alternative providing the same.