# Root check for Android device

Tags: android

This is an old question and asked answered by many but here I go again.. I want to check whether the device is rooted or not. I don't want my application to be installed on rooted devices. Now I went through lot of answers and came to a conclusion that there is no guaranteed way to identify root, correct me if I am wrong. 
Now my question that can we check the device is genuine or not instead of checking for rooted or nor?
Are there any application in which I can test my signed APK for code signing, ssl pinning, code exposure and lot many things?

Comment: A rooted device has an open bootloader most of the times. also it will have busybox installed 90% of times. But all this aside. Google Play Store just released an option for developers to hide their app for rooted devices. Which sure does not forbid it but just makes it a little bit harder for them to get. 
Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device
Article for hiding apps in play store: http://www.androidguys.com/2017/05/19/google-makes-it-easier-for-devs-to-hide-apps-from-rooted-phone-owners/

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424195/determining-if-an-android-device-is-rooted-programatically

Comment: No.  What defines a "genuine" device?  There's no definition for that.

Comment: @Nico Of course they can trivially side load it.  And I expect that setting to work for about another month before its worked around.

Comment: In the article I just read there is an API called `SafetyNet API` which seems to prevent sideloading and installing on rooted devices. Maybe that's worth a shot.

Comment: @GabeSechan as this document states https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/index.html

Comment: @GaneshGhodake That doesn't mean a device is "genuine".  It means that they paid Google to get access to Google's apps (like maps, play store, etc).  A tablet running the AOSP without Google apps is still a real Android device (and the majority of devices in many areas of the world).  Also, its fairly easy to get around.

Answer (score 4):

Below is my utility class for Root Checking.here is String Constants that i have used this is working for me.

```
public static final String[] knownRootAppsPackages = {
            "com.noshufou.android.su",
            "com.noshufou.android.su.elite",
            "eu.chainfire.supersu",
            "com.koushikdutta.superuser",
            "com.thirdparty.superuser",
            "com.yellowes.su",
            "com.zachspong.temprootremovejb",
            "com.ramdroid.appquarantine",
            "eu.chainfire.supersu"

    };

    public static final String[] knownDangerousAppsPackages = {
            "com.koushikdutta.rommanager",
            "com.koushikdutta.rommanager.license",
            "com.dimonvideo.luckypatcher",
            "com.chelpus.lackypatch",
            "com.ramdroid.appquarantine",
            "com.ramdroid.appquarantinepro"
    };

    public static final String[] knownRootCloakingPackages = {
            "com.devadvance.rootcloak",
            "com.devadvance.rootcloakplus",
            "de.robv.android.xposed.installer",
            "com.saurik.substrate",
            "com.zachspong.temprootremovejb",
            "com.amphoras.hidemyroot",
            "com.amphoras.hidemyrootadfree",
            "com.formyhm.hiderootPremium",
            "com.formyhm.hideroot"
    };

    public static final String[] suPaths ={
            "/data/local/",
            "/data/local/bin/",
            "/data/local/xbin/",
            "/sbin/",
            "/su/bin/",
            "/system/bin/",
            "/system/bin/.ext/",
            "/system/bin/failsafe/",
            "/system/sd/xbin/",
            "/system/usr/we-need-root/",
            "/system/xbin/"
    };


    public static final String[] pathsThatShouldNotBeWrtiable = {
            "/system",
            "/system/bin",
            "/system/sbin",
            "/system/xbin",
            "/vendor/bin",
            //"/sys",
            "/sbin",
            "/etc",
            //"/proc",
            //"/dev"
    }
```

;

```
    public class RootUtil {
    public static boolean isDeviceRooted() {
        return detectRootManagementApps() || detectPotentiallyDangerousApps() || checkForBinary("su")
                || checkForBinary("busybox") || checkForDangerousProps() || checkForRWPaths()
                || detectTestKeys() || checkSuExists();
    }

    public static boolean detectTestKeys() {
        String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
        String buildFinger= Build.FINGERPRINT;
        String product=Build.PRODUCT;
        String hardware=Build.HARDWARE;
        String display=Build.DISPLAY;
        return (buildTags != null) && (buildTags.contains("test-keys")|| buildFinger.contains("genric.*test-keys")||product.contains("generic")||product.contains("sdk")||hardware.contains("goldfish")||display.contains(".*test-keys"));
    }


    public static boolean detectRootManagementApps() {
        return detectRootManagementApps(null);
    }


    public static boolean detectRootManagementApps(String[] additionalRootManagementApps) {


        ArrayList<String> packages = new ArrayList<>();
        packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(Constants.knownRootAppsPackages));
        if (additionalRootManagementApps!=null && additionalRootManagementApps.length>0){
            packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(additionalRootManagementApps));
        }

        return isAnyPackageFromListInstalled(packages);
    }


    public static boolean detectPotentiallyDangerousApps() {
        return detectPotentiallyDangerousApps(null);
    }

    public static boolean detectPotentiallyDangerousApps(String[] additionalDangerousApps) {


        ArrayList<String> packages = new ArrayList<>();
        packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(Constants.knownDangerousAppsPackages));
        if (additionalDangerousApps!=null && additionalDangerousApps.length>0){
            packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(additionalDangerousApps));
        }

        return isAnyPackageFromListInstalled(packages);
    }


    public boolean detectRootCloakingApps() {
        return detectRootCloakingApps(null);
    }


    public boolean detectRootCloakingApps(String[] additionalRootCloakingApps) {


        ArrayList<String> packages = new ArrayList<>();
        packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(Constants.knownRootCloakingPackages));
        if (additionalRootCloakingApps!=null && additionalRootCloakingApps.length>0){
            packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(additionalRootCloakingApps));
        }

        return isAnyPackageFromListInstalled(packages);
    }



    public boolean checkForSuBinary(){
        return checkForBinary("su");
    }


    public boolean checkForBusyBoxBinary(){
        return checkForBinary("busybox");
    }

    public static boolean checkForBinary(String filename) {

        String[] pathsArray = Constants.suPaths;

        boolean result = false;

        for (String path : pathsArray) {
            String completePath = path + filename;
            File f = new File(completePath);
            boolean fileExists = f.exists();
            if (fileExists) {
                result = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String[] propsReader() {
        InputStream inputstream = null;
        try {
            inputstream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop").getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String propval = "";
        try {
            propval = new Scanner(inputstream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();

        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {

        }

        return propval.split("\n");
    }

    private static String[] mountReader() {
        InputStream inputstream = null;
        try {
            inputstream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount").getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (inputstream == null) return null;

        String propval = "";
        try {
            propval = new Scanner(inputstream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return propval.split("\n");
    }

    private static boolean isAnyPackageFromListInstalled(List<String> packages){
        boolean result = false;

        PackageManager pm = MobileTechnicianApp.getAppContext().getPackageManager();

        for (String packageName : packages) {
            try {
                pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
                result = true;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static boolean checkForDangerousProps() {

        final Map<String, String> dangerousProps = new HashMap<>();
        dangerousProps.put("ro.debuggable", "1");
        dangerousProps.put("ro.secure", "0");

        boolean result = false;

        String[] lines = propsReader();
        for (String line : lines) {
            for (String key : dangerousProps.keySet()) {
                if (line.contains(key)) {
                    String badValue = dangerousProps.get(key);
                    badValue = "[" + badValue + "]";
                    if (line.contains(badValue)) {
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean checkForRWPaths() {

        boolean result = false;

        String[] lines = mountReader();
        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] args = line.split(" ");

            if (args.length < 4){
                continue;
            }

            String mountPoint = args[1];
            String mountOptions = args[3];

            for(String pathToCheck: Constants.pathsThatShouldNotBeWrtiable) {
                if (mountPoint.equalsIgnoreCase(pathToCheck)) {
                    for (String option : mountOptions.split(",")){

                        if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("rw")){
                            result = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static boolean checkSuExists() {
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "which", "su" });
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            return in.readLine() != null;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (process != null) process.destroy();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i have implemented and checked

Comment: based on current android code need to replace: if (args.length < 6) {
                    continue;
                }
                String mountPoint = args[2];
                String mountOptions = args[5];

Comment: and next: for (String option : mountOptions.replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "").split(",")){

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to check root with `firebase-crashlytics`. Static method from `com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CommonUtils.isRooted(Context)` check root but also it's check `isEmulator`

Answer (score 1):

Check this link: [Determine if running on a rooted device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device/8097801#8097801)

Found some methods to check that device is root or not. It is working fine.

**DemoActivity.class**

```
if (isDeviceRooted()) {
            DialogFactory.getInstance().showAlertDialog(this, null, 0, "This application can't run on Rooted android phone", "Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finishAffinity();
                }
            }, false);
        }
        else {
/* Do your code */
}

public static boolean isDeviceRooted() {
        return Utils.checkRootMethod1() || Utils.checkRootMethod2() || Utils.checkRootMethod3();
    }
```

**Utils.class**

```
public static boolean checkRootMethod1() {
        String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
        return buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys");
    }

public static boolean checkRootMethod2() {
    String[] paths = {"/system/app/Superuser.apk", "/sbin/su", "/system/bin/su", "/system/xbin/su", "/data/local/xbin/su", "/data/local/bin/su", "/system/sd/xbin/su",
            "/system/bin/failsafe/su", "/data/local/su", "/su/bin/su"};
    for (String path : paths) {
        if (new File(path).exists()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean checkRootMethod3() {
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/xbin/which", "su"});
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        return in.readLine() != null;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (process != null) process.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: These methods seem to be identical to this answer back in 2011 https://stackoverflow.com/a/8097801/279320.

Answer (score 1):

Using google SafetyNet Attestation API you can easily check that if the device is genuine or not.

1. Add dependency in build.gradle(:app)

   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
2. Get Api key and enable Android Device Verification API using [link](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation.html#obtain-api-key)
3. Add this method into your project and call from anywhere you want  to check the values authenticity of device.

public static void sendSafetyNetRequest(Activity context) {

```
 if(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context,
 13000000) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

 Log.e(TAG, "The SafetyNet Attestation API is available");

 // TODO(developer): Change the nonce generation to include your own, used once value,
 // ideally from your remote server.

 String nonceData = "Safety Net Sample: " + System.currentTimeMillis();
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 Random mRandom = new SecureRandom();

 byte[] bytes = new byte[24];
 mRandom.nextBytes(bytes);
 try {
     byteStream.write(bytes);
     byteStream.write(nonceData.getBytes());
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

 byte[] nonce = byteStream.toByteArray();

 SafetyNetClient client = SafetyNet.getClient(context);
 Task<SafetyNetApi.AttestationResponse> task = client.attest(nonce, API_KEY_FROM_STEP_2_LINK);

 task.addOnSuccessListener(context, attestationResponse -> {


   /*
          TODO(developer): Forward this result to your server together with
          the nonce for verification.
          You can also parse the JwsResult locally to confirm that the API
          returned a response by checking for an 'error' field first and before
          retrying the request with an exponential backoff.
          NOTE: Do NOT rely on a local, client-side only check for security, you
          must verify the response on a remote server!
         */

     String jwsResult = attestationResponse.getJwsResult();

     Log.e(TAG, "Success! SafetyNet result:\n" + jwsResult + "\n");

     if (jwsResult == null) {
         Log.e(TAG, "jwsResult Null");

     }
     final String[] jwtParts = jwsResult.split("\\.");

     if (jwtParts.length == 3) {
         String decodedPayload = new String(Base64.decode(jwtParts[1], Base64.DEFAULT));
         Log.e(TAG, "decodedPayload :     " + decodedPayload);
     }


 });

 task.addOnFailureListener(context, e -> {
     // An error occurred while communicating with the service.
     String mResult = null;

     if (e instanceof ApiException) {
         // An error with the Google Play Services API contains some additional details.
         ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;

         Util.showLog(TAG, "Error: " +
                 CommonStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(apiException.getStatusCode()) + ": " +
                 apiException.getStatusMessage());
     } else {
         // A different, unknown type of error occurred.
        Log.e(TAG, "ERROR! " + e.getMessage());
     }

 });

} else {
  Log.e(TAG, "Prompt user to update Google Play services.";

}
}
```

4. Check your logs for decodedPayload if ctsProfileMatch and basicIntegrity and check the values in table . The Attestation API returns a JWS response which looks like:

`{ "nonce": "6pLrr9zWyl6TNzj+kpbR4LZcfPY3U2FmZXR5IE5ldCBTYW1wbGU6IDE2MTQ2NzkwMTIzNjc=", "timestampMs": 9860437986543, "apkPackageName": " your package name will be displayed here", "ctsProfileMatch": true, "apkDigestSha256": [ "base64 encoded, SHA-256 hash of the certificate used to sign requesting app" ], "basicIntegrity": true, "evaluationType": "BASIC" }`

[[image: basicIntegrity & ctsProfileMatch status 2]

Answer (score 0):

Implementation Class

```
  if(DeviceUtils.isDeviceRooted()){
                        showAlertDialogAndExitApp("This device is rooted. You can't use this app.");
                    }else{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("My_notification","2");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

showing dialog

```
  public void showAlertDialogAndExitApp(String message) {

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreen.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Root device checking class

```
    public class DeviceUtils {

    public static boolean isDeviceRooted() {
        return checkRootMethod1() || checkRootMethod2() ||
                checkRootMethod3();
    }
    private static boolean checkRootMethod1() {
        String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
        return buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys");
    }
    private static boolean checkRootMethod2() {
        String[] paths = { "/system/app/Superuser.apk", "/sbin/su", "/system/bin/su",
                "/system/xbin/su", "/data/local/xbin/su", "/data/local/bin/su", "/system/sd/xbin/su",
                "/system/bin/failsafe/su", "/data/local/su" };
        for (String path : paths) {
            if (new File(path).exists()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private static boolean checkRootMethod3() {
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
                    "/system/xbin/which", "su" });
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            if (in.readLine() != null) return true;
            return false;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (process != null) process.destroy();
        }
    }
   }
```