# Rooted Device Installation MFP 8

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

Need to block the installation in ROOTED device from MFP APP. Currently, app installed properly but the connections are blocked but I need to block during app installation.

how to do ?

Comment: what is MFP? Where from is the application going to be installed?

Comment: check this might help 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_configuring_trusteer.html

Comment: MobileFirstPlatform (MFP), I created an APK with my source code.

@manjunathkallannavar: can u pl share an idea for MFP 8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Verifying if the device is rooted, is not a feature in built in MFP SDK. You can do this:

a) [programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424195/determining-if-an-android-device-is-rooted-programmatically) or

b) [use 3rd party plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-root-detection)