# Android Root Check fails on samsung tab while executin /system/bin/which su

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have followed the link [Determining if an Android device is rooted programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424195/determining-if-an-android-device-is-rooted-programmatically/8009677)
to have a check if the application is running on a rooted android device. For some devices and emulator its working fine but for my new Samsung tablet, it's failing.

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/which su ");
```

After executingg the above line it returns `true`.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

public class RootUtil {

```
private static final String TAG = "RootUtil";

public static boolean isDeviceRooted() {
    return checkRootMethod1() || checkRootMethod2() || checkRootMethod3();
}

private static boolean checkRootMethod1() {
    String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
    return buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys");
}

private static boolean checkRootMethod2() {
    String[] paths = {"/system/app/Superuser.apk", "/sbin/su", "/system/bin/su", "/system/xbin/su", "/data/local/xbin/su", "/data/local/bin/su", "/system/sd/xbin/su",
            "/system/bin/failsafe/su", "/data/local/su", "/su/bin/su"};
    for (String path : paths) {
        if (new File(path).exists()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean checkRootMethod3() {
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/xbin/which", "su"});
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        return in.readLine() != null;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (process != null) process.destroy();
    }
}

public static boolean isDeviceRootedV2() {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "isDeviceRootedV2: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: call isDeviceRootedV2() for root check

Comment: If you please refer to the link I shared this command is there.