# how to detect Screen recording in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to detect if screen is getting captured for my app in flutter? I want to turn my screen black if any app/system is recoding screen while my app is active.
Is it possible in flutter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent screen-record in an flutter-based application on iOS and android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432233/how-to-prevent-screen-record-in-an-flutter-based-application-on-ios-and-android)

Comment: Solution suggested by @AminSamani should work.

Comment: What I want is, User is free to take screenshot but cannot record screen. As per comment by @AminSamani , both will be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin [flutter_windowmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager)
to prevent screen shot and video record

in main file :

```
  disableCapure() async {
     await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);  
  }
```

then call that method after runApp

```
  void main(){
    runApp(...);
    disableCapure();
  }
```

although for ios you have to know native code maybe it not work pretty for ios

Comment: what about audio?