# Prevent only single screen recording or screenshot capture on single screen in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, screenshot, flutter-dependencies, screen-recording

Found many solutions to prevent the screenshots in flutter and this solutions needs to write code in native android and iOS files. If we do it in native file of iOS or android then it applies for all the screens in flutter. But my requirement is to prevent screen recording only for single screen in flutter. I don't want to prevent screenshots on all other screens in flutter app.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432233/how-to-prevent-screen-record-in-an-flutter-based-application-on-ios-and-android and https://mrgulshanyadav.medium.com/prevent-screenshot-and-video-recording-in-flutter-93839325d66c

Comment: @stacktrace2234 Both solutions work fine on android but not on iOS. also it will not achieve my problem.