# Check if I have root access on my mobile phone

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I recently bought a new Samsung Galaxy A7 mobile phone with 3GB RAM and 16 GB ROM. The entire lot of the 3GB ram is taken up and there seems to be no room to install more applications. Hence I used `Smart Manager` to kill some of the processes that I have never used. But these processes keep turning themselves on the phone and return almost immediately. I want to check if I have root access to delete these unwanted processes.

Since this phone is not tethered to a Internet connection, I don't want to risk tethering my phone before I can control the processes running inside it. I really dont want to install external programs or utilities to see if I have root access.

Is there a way that I can check the root access to my phone, any methods to see what processes are taking so much RAM of the phone?

I see these two links [link1][1] and [link2][2] which do talk about writing code to find out whether I have root access.

I am naive to the programming and will take time to write the Python equivalent of the given and then use it understand the root access, and use the root access to kill the unwanted processes.

Are there any inbuilt tools within the Android mobile that allow you to check what process are consuming so much RAM?

Thanks in advance.

(1) [How to check root access in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736411/how-to-check-root-access-in-android)
(2) [How to check root access in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736411/how-to-check-root-access-in-android)

Comment: You dont install application on the RAM. You dont need to care about the RAM Android is always using (almost) all RAM for better performance. If you cant install apps its becouse you are out of storage. Samsung devices arent rooted and youll probably lost warranty if you root it

Comment: 1. Samsung devices are not rooted by default, so unless you rooted it (or bought it from someone who rooted it), it's not rooted. 2. Apps are not installed in RAM 3. This is off-topic because SO is for programming-related questions, which this is not.

Comment: 1. I could still write code to see if I can see if I have root access for which I need to have knowledge which is where this question plays a role.  So this question is relevant here

Answer (score 0):

1) ensure you have rooted your device which is not by default.
2) install & set up adb, Wiki: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html
3) login adb shell and kill processes

```
adb shell
su
ps -al 
kill [process]
```

adb shell wiki: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html