# How can I disable Activesync if I detect a rooted phone on Android?

Tags: android, activesync

I found a few ways to [detect a rooted Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1101380/328397), but I would now like to use that functionality to whitelist (or blacklist) users who root with activesync.

What are my implementation options here?

Comment: Um, ActiveSync is a Microsoft concept, having little to do with Android and less to do with rooting a phone.

Comment: The idea is that if the phone is rooted, perhaps I can kill Activesync

Comment: There is no ActiveSync to be killed. ActiveSync is a Microsoft concept, having little to do with Android and less to do with rooting a phone. Android has Exchange support, and it is possible that uses the same protocols as ActiveSync, but that's all there is, AFAIK.

Comment: The relation is that a rooted Android phone might pose a security risk to a corporate org that relies on Activesync. (Improper Process Elevation, etc)  In that case, I want to support disabling Activesync for phones in this configuration.

Comment: Since there is no ActiveSync to be disabled, you are already done.

Comment: @CommonsWare Android uses Activesync to connect to Exchange.  It exists, and I see it occurring before my eyes.  It seems you are unaware of the feature

Comment: You are massively confused, but, be that as it may... Most Android devices can connect to Exchange nowadays, as it was added as a feature in Android 2.0. Hence, your blacklist will be ~99% of all devices. Moreover, your only way to disable it will be to replace the firmware with one that does not support Exchange synchronization.

Comment: @CommonsWare If you assert I'm confused, please elaborate. (I've been an Exchange admin for 15 years) If 2.0 devices are not using Activesync, what is it?  Possible options are POP3, IMAP, EWS, OWA, Activesync

Comment: Various things get the ActiveSync label. I tend to think of software. Android does not use ActiveSync software from Microsoft for Exchange synchronization. ActiveSync is also a protocol. Android's Exchange synchronization does use the protocol. You do not disable a protocol; you might disable software that implements the protocol. You do not kill a protocol; you might kill software that implements the protocol. Now, my own confusion was forgetting that ActiveSync is the name of the protocol as well as the software (I thought MS used a different term) and for that I apologize.

Comment: I'm quit a bit late here, but can't you just determine their MAC address and then block that device from accessing your Exchange server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ActiveSync client uses the [account manager API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) to sync stuff, thus with the `android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS` you should be able to do stuff like clear the password or at least disable sync / delete the account.

(Deleting the account can lead to all information being removed. Clients usually do not appreciate this)

But.. they'd have to be running software that you've built. So whats stopping them from uninstalling that? They've already got root.