# Android App fails on Rooted SAMSUNG SIII (d2can/d2vzw/d2spr)

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, rooted-device

I have a published Android Application that incorporates Audio processing, e.g. Recording/Playback of RAW format.
My recording code for RAW files is based on the Rehersal Assistant app from URBAN STEW, and my app works fine on NON rooted Samsungs.
There seems to be an issue with Rooted Samsung Siii devices.
Most of my 1 star reviews are all from Samsung Galaxy Siii (d2can/d2vzw/d2spr) users.
Why would "rooting" affect AUDIO procesing?
How do i amend my application to also work seamlessly on rooted phones?
Is it possible to detect when a device has been rooted?

Comment: You can check out this post to check your app is running on rooted device http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device

Comment: It may be a problem with the root app. Are those users all using SuperSU? Or are they all Superuser users? If so, contact the devs.