# Verify Root Access: How to do?

Tags: java, android, root

I wanted to know how I can do to see if there are root permissions. What education do I use to verify that in / bin there is the su file? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device

Comment: I apologize. I had not seen. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
ls /bin
```

and see what you get