# Restricting an application to be installed on a rooted device

Tags: android, ios, mobile, phonegap-plugins

I have developed a mobile application in PhoneGap. We had a security test on the application and it has flagged that application can be installed on a rooted device and we don't want to allow this. Is there a way to restrict an application to be installed on a jailbreak phone using phonegap

Thanks

Comment: All apps can be installed on a rooted device. You should view with skepticism anything else that this "test" reports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The short answer**

No, you can't at install time.

**The long answer**

You can restrict the installation on devices by two ways:

- Using the uses-feature meta tag in the manifest. Check out the doc [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html).
- Via the android console, where you can manage restrictions on any model by excluding or including some of them as target for the install of your application.

Since the root is not a feature implemented as part of the device, it is a software restriction, you might accept users to install the application and check it at runtime if the device is rooted. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device) on how you can try to do it, but there is not an official way or consistent for all devices as far as I know.