# How to prevent application to install on rooted devices

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working on an application that have some security issues on rooted devices. I want to strict app to install only on non rooted devices is it possible ? or i have to check on launcher activity if its rooted then finish or some thing like that ?

Comment: Do a quick search on Google next time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device

Comment: Martin as you can see on my question my question is do we have to check in out activity or is it possible to only install application on no-rooted device hope you will get my question.

Comment: No, you can't do anything before the application is installed. The Google Play store allows access to rooted devices.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot restrict installation on rooted device. But what you can do is, in your app check whether the device is rooted. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8097801/931982) is a similar answer to check if the device is rooted.