# Android: How to detect a rooting in Android App

Tags: android

I want to know how to detect a rooting in a Android App.

Comment: Read the rules for StackOverflow... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What @LucasCrawford said. I am quite new here myself, but quickly came to learn that Stack Overflow isn't just any old forum, there are rules in place to help create a professional Q&A environment. Read the rules, and you will come to appreciate what Stack Overflow can offer you.

Comment: Sorry, I did sign up yesterday. so i don't know rules.  please understand generously.

Answer (score 5):

This has been answered before, but here it goes:

I had this issue some time ago, and there does not seem to be one failsafe method to do this. For most scenarios however, you could check several characteristics that might point to a device being rooted, but again, this is not guaranteed to work every time.

Check out [**this previous answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device) regarding the issue, and remember; **do not just copy and paste. Build an understanding of the code, so that you may learn something in the process**.

Next time, try to do some more research before asking questions, Stack Overflow is filled to the brim with great questions and answers. Good luck with your app!

Comment: Then the proper action would have been to flag this question as a possible duplicate of the other.

Comment: @cfi I actually assumed I did not have enough reputation to do such things, I see now that I was wrong. However, I think it being "put on hold as too broad" is even more to the point. Also, because the asker is new here, I thought to give him/ her a pointer to a suitable answer as well as give him/ her some "next time"-advice