# Detecting rooted device on Android 6

Tags: android, root

i have some methods for root detection.

```
final boolean t1 = canExecuteCommand("/system/bin/which su");
final boolean t2 = canExecuteCommand("which su");

private static boolean canExecuteCommand(String command)
{
    boolean executedSuccesfully;
    try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
      executedSuccesfully = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      executedSuccesfully = false;
    }

    return executedSuccesfully;
}
```

Everything works fine until Android 6. From that version A6 return TRUE on t1 and t2. My device is not rooted. I updated device from A5 to A6 using system update.

Why is return true from A6?
Thanks.

Comment: There are 4-5 methods available to detect root. Check once [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device)

Comment: I have implemented all of them. But only these 2 tests not work from A6 (Lenovo A7000).