# Can a web application determine if a Chromecast has been rooted or jailbroken?

Tags: html, web-applications, chromecast, jailbreak, rooted-device

Is it possible to develop a web application for a Chromecast that can determine if the Chromecast has been rooted or jailbroken?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device?noredirect=1&lq=1) if it can help you.