# Is this a reliable way to test for root on Android?

Tags: android

I'm making an app that needs to check for root access. I found some solutions here on StackOverflow, but they involved checking hard paths for known root binaries, which isn't really all that universal, so I wanted to avoid using that.

At first, I made a new Process to execute `su`, then checked its InputStream for strings like "not found" or "permission denied." I thought that worked, until I tried it on an Android 4.1 emulator, where the InputStream is completely different from the StackTrace returned in an exception.

After a while, I came up with this function:

```
private boolean testSudo() {
    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = new StackTraceElement[] { null };
    try{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        stackTrace = e.getStackTrace();
    }

    return stackTrace == null;
}
```

What I'm wondering is, is this actually a reliable method? In theory, it returns true when the StackTrace remains null, but returns false if something has been added to it. To me, it looks universal, but so did my old method.

EDIT: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380) doesn't answer my question. I'm not asking *how* to check for root, but rather if my method is accurate, or if there are any glaring flaws.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if running on a rooted device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device)

Answer (score 3):

You can consider to use [RootBeer](https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer). It It uses various checks to indicate whether device is rooted or not.

As simple as

```
RootBeer rootBeer = new RootBeer(context);
if(rootBeer.isRooted()){

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more interested in knowing whether or not what I've made is actually a good solution. Looking at the source of that, it looks like it also does the common checks for existing SU binaries, root apps, etc, which can all give false positives. My app is looking for root to use it or use a non-root alternative.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually found that isn't a reliable method, namely because `stackTrace` is never null. Changing

```
return stackTrace == null;
```

to

```
return stackTrace[0] == null;
```

makes it work.