# How to check if the device is rooted in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Is there any plugin in Flutter to check if the device is rooted or not. I'm a beginner in Mobile App Development and as far as I know there are some system directories that need to be searched for **su** binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be no plugin for this at this point at https://pub.dartlang.org.

You might be able to create a plugin using native android code and Flutter Platform Channels (Platform Channels -- It's the flexible system used by Flutter that allows you to call platform-specific APIs whether available in Java or Kotlin code on Android, or in ObjectiveC or Swift code on iOS.)

- For native android code to check if the device is rooted : [Determine if running on a rooted device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device)
- About Flutter Platform channels : https://flutter.io/platform-channels/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will look into it, thanks!

Comment: There is a package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/trust_fall

Comment: The problem with `trust_fall` is it is not *null-safe*. Another alternative would be [root_access](https://pub.dev/packages/root_access), but that only works on Android.