# Detect GameGuardian Installed on the Android/Prevent Game Guardian from modifying values

Tags: android, anti-cheat, guardian

Good day. I am trying to find a way to detect game guardian apk installed on the Android OS. Google didn't give any answers so I came here. The issue is that Game Guardian is installing different apk on it's initial launch with some random package name. Anyone has any suggestion how to protect application from being modified by Game Guardian?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I've just read on the official game guardian page, Game guardian works on only rooted devices or Emulators so an easy implementation would be to make your app detect for rooting applications, hacking tools or super user binaries on the devices on launch and prompt to uninstall or quit if any is detected it should also verify if the device the game is being played on is an authentic device or an emulator and prompt to uninstall if the latter. There are multiple ways which this can be done a quick google search on preventing application from running on rooted devices should be fruitful. However i have included some links to shorten the process :

[Android device rooted check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53082905/android-device-rooted-check)

https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer

https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/android-root-detection-bypass-reverse-engineering-apk/

[How to prevent Rooted Android Phones from Installing my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540545/how-to-prevent-rooted-android-phones-from-installing-my-app)

https://www.androidauthority.com/google-play-store-apps-download-block-root-users-773824/

Comment: Why do you consider recommending another technique as an answer to the question? The question clearly wants to detect Game Gauardian app not if the device is rooted or not. The problem is that someone will mark another question as a duplicate of this one.