# How to check if an Android device can be rebooted programmatically?

Tags: android, android-reboot

I am using a Android device having custom ROM and need to reboot that device. I am able to reboot the device from hardware side, but I want to programmatically check if the device can be rebooted.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why you think that the device can be non-rebootable?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko
Tried with stock Android and was not able to reboot.Do all the devices using Custom ROMs are rebootable?

Comment: if you were unable to reboot still does not mean that the device is not rebootable. from the hardware side (the device side) the reboot means power off + power on, or resetting temporal memory (RAM, CPU registers) to empty state + resetting all hardware to default state (camera, wifi, bluetooth, etc.). I'm sure that every android-capable device is ale to do that. As for the software side - by default (without having root permissions) you can't reboot the device programmatically. Also nobody knows how you have tried to reboot it.

Comment: I tried to reboot programatically.  if we have root permission we can reboot android device , is that correct?

Comment: yes, but `Also nobody knows how you have tried to reboot it.`

Comment: Used the following code
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "reboot"});
process.waitFor();

But this is not rebooting in some rooted device

Comment: check the command output to know why

Comment: Please post the source code which you already tried with, that will help others to find any lacking of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Check the device is rooted or not.
If the device is rooted, then request root permission and you can reboot the device.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8097801/10561943) is how to check root access is available or not.